# `pip3 list` showing uninstalled package

Tags: python, pip

Last week I installed `awscli` with pip3, and today I decided to uninstall it. The uninstall was successful, but `pip3 list` gives me the following output:

```
~
❯ pip3 list
Package           Version
----------------- ----------
-                 scli
-wscli            1.16.137
astroid           2.0.4
botocore          1.12.127
certifi           2018.10.15
colorama          0.3.9
docutils          0.14
isort             4.3.4
jmespath          0.9.4
lazy-object-proxy 1.3.1
mccabe            0.6.1
pip               19.0.3
pyasn1            0.4.5
pylint            2.1.1
python-dateutil   2.8.0
PyYAML            3.13
rsa               3.4.2
s3transfer        0.2.0
setuptools        40.8.0
six               1.11.0
urllib3           1.24.1
virtualenv        16.1.0
virtualenv-clone  0.4.0
wheel             0.33.1
wrapt             1.10.11
```

The top two entries appear to be related to `awscli`. Even the version number (1.16.137) is the same as `awscli`'s. Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

EDIT:

Found this:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
❯ ls
__pycache__                       mccabe-0.6.1.dist-info            virtualenv.py
astroid                           mccabe.py                         virtualenv_clone-0.4.0.dist-info
astroid-2.0.4.dist-info           pip                               virtualenv_support
botocore                          pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg-info         wheel
botocore-1.12.130.dist-info       pkg_resources                     wheel-0.32.2-py3.7.egg-info
certifi                           pylint                            wheel-0.33.0-py3.7.egg-info
certifi-2018.10.15.dist-info      pylint-2.1.1.dist-info            wheel-0.33.1-py3.7.egg-info
clonevirtualenv.py                setuptools                        wrapt
easy_install.py                   setuptools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg-info  wrapt-1.10.11.dist-info
isort                             sitecustomize.py                  ~-scli-1.16.137.dist-info
isort-4.3.4.dist-info             six-1.11.0.dist-info              ~wscli-1.16.137.dist-info
lazy_object_proxy                 six.py
lazy_object_proxy-1.3.1.dist-info virtualenv-16.1.0.dist-info
```

Safe to delete the two offending directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pip list` takes this information from `.dist-info` entries in your path. You appear to have some extra names there, given your listing. Note the two entries at the end:

```
~-scli-1.16.137.dist-info
~wscli-1.16.137.dist-info
```

Simply delete these two directory entries.

Note that `awscli` did not create these directories, especially because pip would have used the [universal wheel file to install `awscli`](https://pypi.org/project/awscli/1.16.137/#files), so no setup script needed to be run when it was installed. They remind me of the Windows hidden lock files (which start with `~$`), so perhaps they were created when you used another tool I'm not familiar with that may have accidentally left these lying around.

It doesn't really matter if those `.dist-info` entries are directories, symlinks, or files, all that `pip list` does is take all names that end in `.dist-info` then splits out version and name at the first `-`. You can create any phantom entry just by creating empty files:

```
$ mkdir demo && cd demo && virtualenv-3.8 .
# ....
$ bin/pip list  # new, empty virtualenv
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.0.3
setuptools 41.0.0
wheel      0.33.1
$ touch lib/python3.8/site-packages/foobar-version.dist-info
$ bin/pip list  # surprise package listed
Package    Version
---------- -------
foobar     version
pip        19.0.3
setuptools 41.0.0
wheel      0.33.1
```

Comment: Ended up deleting them. That fixed the problem :)

Comment: @kylemart: I'm trying to reproduce what might have happened, how these two extra 'package' directories might have been added. I'll update if there is more you need to do.

Comment: Yeah, it is pretty strange how they ended up there. I only use pip3 to install my python packages, so I don't think any other tools should be involved. Also, thanks so much for investigating further!